# check which vector is more linear in Matllab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data shared on multiple vector +100, each one contains 14 values. I would like to know which one of them is the most linear. Here is an example:

[image: first]
[image: second]
[image: third]
I 'll say that the order of the linearity it : 3rd plot, then 1st, then 2nd.

my question is, if there is anyway to program that or a mathematical process that can help do that ?

thanks for any help !

Comment: I think that you should be able to use total least squares. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

Comment: What do you mean by the most linear?? Perhaps you want the highest absolute correlation?

Comment: @Dan  I mean which one resemble the most to a line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the curve is a straight line, the differentes between consecutive points are a constant. The more linear a curve is, the more those differences approach the same constant. A simple approach would be to could compute the curve [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) and take the standard deviation:

```
rank = std(diff(curve));
```

`diff(curve)` will calculate the differences between consecutive points on the curve, and `std(...)` will give you a measure of how similar they are.

Then, you take the rank for each curve and then sort them.

Comment: I'll add an explanation.

Comment: @Dan's solution is definitely more robust than mine. Correlation, of course! I guess I'll go drink some coffee.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro I think this solution is just as acceptable - I wouldn't be surprised if they give the same ranking

Comment: I love both your solutions (@Dan & @RafaelMonteiro). Now I am curious to see if one would me more 'precise' than the other (meaning if one solution gives an equal score for 2 curves, would the other solution give an equal score as well). Dan's solution looks more 'robust' and mathematically engineered, while Rafael's is certainly 'creative', and has the great merit to not require any additional toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

The absolute of the correlation should give you a good measure:

```
abs(corr(your_vector(:), (1:numel(your_vector))'))
```

The closer this value is to `1`, the closer your data is to lying in a straight line, the closer to `0` it is, the less your data resembles a straight line

As others have mentioned, R<sup>2</sup> is the best measure. So this would be

```
corr(your_vector(:), (1:numel(your_vector))')^2
```

but using `abs` gives you the same ranking.

Comment: I would just change the `14` to `numel(your_vector)`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`fit`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/curvefit/fit.html) with `Linear polynomial curve` option which is `'poly1'` for this function to see how good is the fit -

```
[curve,goodness] = fit(x, y,  'poly1')
```

It produces bunch of values with `goodness` variable. For a sample, it produced something like this -

goodness =

```
       sse: 0.1007
   rsquare: 0.9819
       dfe: 12
adjrsquare: 0.9804
      rmse: 0.0916
```

Out of these `sse` and `rmse` that are `Sum of squares due to error` and `Root mean squarederror (standard error)` respectively looked interesting and I think either one of them could be used as a measure of "linearity"

Comment: I would go with the `rsquare` as a measure as it won't be dependent on the vertical scale of the data. `rsquare` is just the square of the same correlation coefficient I proposed.

Comment: This one doesn't depend either on the vertical scaling. Results coming up.

Comment: `sse` and `rmse` will sure depend on the vertical scale, if the scale is huge then we can expect the errors to be huge. Where as `rsquared` is scaled to fall between 0 and 1

Comment: Ah right, I meant the slope of data won't affect the results, but yes the stretch of `y` would have an impact on it. I guess `sse` or `rmse` have to be normalized, just like the `rsquare` is.

Comment: More processing, but you could calculate the (original_curve - fit_line). That would remove the 'trend' and produce a curve centered on an horizontal line, you can then forget about the `y` span.

Comment: @Hoki, no you still can't forget about the y-span. If the standard deviation of your detrended line is large the errors will be large and this depends on scale.

Answer (score 2):

The standard measure would be to assess [R<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).